# Disabling reusage of evil scroll count

Tags: evil, scrolling

If `evil-scroll-line-down` is not given a count argument, the last count is used.  This is not the behaviour of vim, which scrolls one line if no count is specified. How can I get vim behaviour?

Comment: Please report a bug at https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil

Comment: I've added it myself to their issue tracker.

Answer (score 1):

This has been resolved almost a month ago: https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil/issues/790

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, you should re-bind `C-e` (and `C-y`) as follows:

```
(evil-define-command my/evil-scroll-line-down (count)
  :repeat nil
  :keep-visual t
  (interactive "<c>")
  (progn
    ;; scroll...
    (evil-scroll-line-down count)
    ;; ...then, reset counter
    (setq evil-scroll-line-count 1)))
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-e") #'my/evil-scroll-line-down)
```